# PHP Security screencasts

Tags: php, video

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a php security video tutorials / screencast. I looked on the likes of lynda.com - but couldn't see anything.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not video tutorials but some slide shows of PHP security presentations from doing a quick google search

[www.slideshare.net/csixty4/intro-to-php-security](http://www.slideshare.net/csixty4/intro-to-php-security)

[www.slideshare.net/kschroeder/php-security-common-2011](http://www.slideshare.net/kschroeder/php-security-common-2011)

[www.slideshare.net/dseguy/php-security-audits](http://www.slideshare.net/dseguy/php-security-audits)

[www.slideshare.net/ctankersley/php-security-tips](http://www.slideshare.net/ctankersley/php-security-tips)